# Failure in printing OSM as a basemap through GeoServer Mapfish Plugin

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, basemap, mapfish

I am trying to print OSM as a basemap through GeoServer. The WMS typed layer gets printed but the OSM doesn't. The projection coordinates I am using is ESPG:4236. But I found that the majority of OSM basemap through GeoServer uses ESPG:900913 coordinates. However I somehow managed to pull some data from online research for 4326 cordinates as shown below. I am not sure whether I can do like this or not.

### spec.json

```
{
  "layout":size,
  "srs":"EPSG:4326",
  "units":"degrees",
  "dpi":dpi,
  "layers":[
    {
      "baseURL":"http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org",
      "extension":"png",
      "opacity":1,
      "singleTile":false,
      "type":"OSM",
      "maxExtent":[80.05844110511946,26.34796713166333,88.20152186778043,30.447429596886728],
      "tileSize":[256,256],
      "resolutions":[5.625,2.813,1.406,0.703,0.352,0.176,0.088,0.044,0.022,0.011,0.005,0.003,0.001,0.0005]
    },
    {
      "baseURL":"http://localhost:9090/geoserver/BernHardt_Practical/wms",
      "opacity":1.0,
      "singleTile":false,
      "type":"WMS",
      "layers":["Nepal"],
      "format":"image/png"
    }
  ],
  "pages":[
    { 
      "bbox":[80.05844110511946, 26.34796713166333, 88.20152186778043, 30.447429596886728],
      "scale":scale,
      "strictEpsg4326": true
    }
  ]
};
```

I am not receiving any errors, but no OSM basemap layer is being drawn except the WMS layer. This is the output I am getting.

### Imcomplete Output:

[image: Incomplete output(Only WMS layer printed not OSM)]

The output should have been like this,
[image]

Do we have any other proper resolutions?

Comment: what is in the log file? what value does dpi have?

Comment: Inside log file, I found these.
 ERROR [print.PDFUtils] Server returned an error for http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/09/0/-1.png: Error (status=404) while reading the image from http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/09/0/-1.png: Not Found 
 ERROR [print.PDFCustomBlocks] - Error while adding a PDF elementjava.io.IOException: Error (status=404) while reading the image from http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/09/0/-1.png: Not Found

And dpi is either 75 or 150 or 300 based on option selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the projection that you are using. As far as I know, OSM map is in **ESPG:900913**. Using any projection other than EPSG:900913 might cause some issues while generating the map. Also, I think the maxExtent for the OSM layer should be the extent of the entire map which is **[-20037508.3392,-20037508.3392,20037508.3392,20037508.3392]**.
I have made some corrections. Please try. Hope it works.

### spec.json

```
{
        "layout":"A4 portrait",
        "srs": "EPSG:900913",
        "units":"m",
        "dpi":150,
        "mapTitle":"Map Title",
        "comment":"This is my comment.",
        "outputFilename":"test",
        "layers":[
          {
            "baseURL":"http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org",
            "singleTile":false,
            "type":"OSM",
            "maxExtent":[-20037508.3392,-20037508.3392,20037508.3392,20037508.3392],
            "tileSize":[256,256],
            "extension":"png",
            "resolutions":[156543.03390625,78271.516953125,39135.758475, 19567.8792375, 9783.93961875, 4891.969809375, 2445.9849046875, 1222.99245256282, 611.496226171875, 305.7481130859375, 152.87405654296876, 76.43702827148438, 38.21851413574219, 19.109257067871095, 9.554628533935547, 4.777314266967774, 2.388657133483887, 1.1943285667419434, 0.5971642833709717,0.41999977320012255, 0.2799998488000817,0.13999992440004086, 0.08399995464002451, 0.05599996976001634, 0.02799998488000817]
          },
          {
            "baseURL":"http://localhost:9090/geoserver/BernHardt_Practical/wms",
            "opacity":1.0,
            "singleTile":false,
            "type":"WMS",
            "layers":["Districts"],
            "format":"image/png"
          }
        ],
        "pages":[
          {
            "bbox":[8999389.96218351,3005099.523314774,9558297.51300472,3567731.121512101],
            "rotation":0
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: Yes it did... Thanks a lot Mr. A. Bhujel. And I was suspecting on Resolutions. Silly me. :)

Comment: Yup! The resolution was also not in EPSG:900913. I forgot to mention that...

Comment: I got that mate. :)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the URL is returning a 404 is the problem. This is probably to do with the -1 in the tile index, the most likely cause of this is a mismatch in the tile origin or the projection.

Comment: I got it. So what shall be done then? I am suspecting the problem might be because of the resolutions that I had provided. 
If there any possible way that I can print the OSM basemap?